# Open CKEDITOR dialog without CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I was triying to open a CKEDITOR dialog without a CKEDITOR editor. I have included the CKEDITOR javascript file and included

```
var dialogObj = new CKEDITOR.dialog( editor, 'smiley' );
```

But obviusly editor is not defined and do not know how to instance it without a CKEDITOR input. I'm using CKEDITOR 3.6.4

¿Any idea?

Comment: Ugh. I think most CKEditor dialogs are bound to an editor instance in some way. This may be *very* difficult. What do you want to do?

Comment: I wanna use just one modalbox in the whole site so I would like to use the ckeditors one for other tasks.

Comment: Meh. I would look for the functionality you desire in a standalone way instead

Answer (score 0):

1 way -> in this case you should add document.ptototype.dialog and customize all dialog plugin according to the need.

2 way-> we can add ckeditor in the page and hide that using css then we can use this